# uninitialized constant Activerecords error while using sync in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronization

I am trying to develop a simple rails app with sync and fyne to synchronise data on web pages on multiple windows. I followed the sync GitHub instructions but I am getting a NameError error in puma.rb while running `rackup sync.ru -E production`. The error log is as follow.

```
config/puma.rb:15:in `block in _load_from': uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Puma::DSL:0x000000026a5b60>>::ActiveSupport (NameError)
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:276:in `block in run_hooks'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:276:in `each'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:276:in `run_hooks'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:260:in `worker'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_workers'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:126:in `fork'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:126:in `block in spawn_workers'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:122:in `times'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:122:in `spawn_workers'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:200:in `check_workers'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:471:in `run'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183:in `run'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.11.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:69:in `run'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:148:in `start'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: make sure you have [active_support gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/5.2.0) installed

Comment: I added the `active_support gem` to the Gemfile but still getting the same error

Comment: can you show your production log

Comment: use may have to require active support in the puma config file